# SQLSTATE[23000] & UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE

Tags: mysql, magento

a few time per day i get the following error (as listed in the reports)

```
a:5:{i:0;s:124:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'catalog_url' for key 'UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE'";i:1;s:1900:"#0 /path-to-magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /path-to-magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /path-to-magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `in...', Array)
#4 /path-to-magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `in...', Array)
#5 /path-to-magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1998): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `in...', Array)
#6 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Setup.php(82): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('index_process', Array, Array)
#7 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Setup.php(45): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->_syncIndexes()
#8 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#9 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#10 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#11 /path-to-magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /path-to-magento/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:98:"/accessoires/peuter_80_98.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I have magento 1.8.1 CE.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found in the index_process table.

The flat_catalog index was disabled but needed reindexing.
Which wasn't shown in the index module of magento